# Speed to load an image in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I got a issue on loading image speed...

I've already published my Application to IIS8 and when I access the web using this `localhost/applicationname` it load real fast

but I change the localhost into the server IP, it takes almost 5 minute to load  an image...

Anyone have this problem before ?

Here is what firebug show:
[image]

Comment: There could be a number of possible causes. Image size is large, network is slow... the more details you give us, the better we can troubleshoot

Comment: the image size is just normal less than 1MB.... i use the server to access the web itself... 

localhost/applicationname = Fast Load
127.0.0.1/applicationname = Fast Load

but when i change it to the IP of the server
172.11.0.80/applicationname = Slow Load

this is what the infomation that i got - -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is not with your application, it's networked based. When you're using the localhost, you're using the loopback IP, your connection is never leaving the local computer. In fact, when you use localhost, you're not even accessing the network hardware.

Comment: @ajieh89, my pleasure - glad to hear that you solved it!